# Совместимость разных компиляторов/линкеров на уровне готовых бинарей

Tags: c++, развертывание, build

Допустим, есть один бинарь общей системы, который был сделан одним компилятором/линкером, а есть другой, сделанный другим. Зависимости статические. Общаются через какой-то IPC вроде сокетов. Могут ли быть какие-нибудь проблемы, связанные с разными компиляторами/линкерами?

Comment: Между ними есть хоть какая-нибудь связь помимо сокетов? Если нет, то и проблем нет, лишь бы в сокете протокол совместимый был

Comment: Надо смотреть какой именно IPC. Проблемы могут быть только с ним.

Comment: @andreymal@Chorkov а можете привести примеры таких, при которых будут проблемы? Например, при использовании шаренного участка памяти?

Comment: Ну если формат содержимого в этом шареном участке памяти будет совместимый, то наверное проблем тоже не будет

Comment: Посмотрите на размерность и выравнивание данных. Может, из-за этого что-то.

Comment: @Никита Размер int-а и char-а может быть разный при разных настройках компилятора.